# Geometric representation for pentahedral numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Triangular numbers are the sum of the integers up to n.

[Tetrahedral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_number) numbers are very similar, and can be shown to represent the number of balls stacked in a pyramid shape.

Is there a name given to 'pentahedral' numbers? And if so, is there a 3 dimensional geometric representation of these numbers?

I would assume that the equation to determine pentahedral numbers would follow from the pattern established from the triangular and tetrahedral numbers:

$T_n={n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\over 4!}$, or ${n^{\overline 4}\over 4!} $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pentahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentahedron) can mean two completely distinct things; however, it is evident that you're refering to a [square pyramid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number): in which case, we seem to be dealing with $P_n=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^nk^2=\frac{n\Big(n+\frac12\Big)(n+1)}3$, see [Faulhaber's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula#Examples).